# Mapbox `loaded` method incorrectly returns false when application is running

Tags: javascript, mapbox, race-condition

I have an application that uses MapboxGL SDK. When user enters certain view, I make single or several requests to server. These requests might also be cached in browser. At the same time, the view is loading a map (`Map` object of the SDK).

The requests then triggers code that adds source and layer to that specific map. Since all of this is asynchronous and I do not want to block UI, what happens is I get sometimes error `Uncaught Error: Style is not done loading`.

This happens only sometimes. The times when it does not happen is when Mapbox map manages to load quicker than server responses that trigger changes to the map.

I have tried using this approach:

```
if (map.loaded()) {
  map.addSource(id, source)
  map.addLayer(layer)
} else {
  map.on('load', () => {
    map.addSource(id, source)
    map.addLayer(layer)
  })
}
```

However this causes some of my layers not being added to the map if the map actually loads quicker than responses (and does not throw the error mentioned above).

When debugging my code, I noticed the method `map.loaded()` actually returns `false` even though the map is already loaded? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have confused what the `loaded()` method actually does and when `load` event is actually fired. I seem to be [not the only one](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6707) that is confused by this and some objections have been raised.

The documentation states for the `load` event:

> Fired immediately after all necessary resources have been downloaded and the first visually complete rendering of the map has occurred.

On the other hand, the docs for `loaded` method state:

> Returns a Boolean indicating whether the map is fully loaded.
> Returns false if the style is not yet fully loaded, or if there has been a change to the sources or style that has not yet fully loaded.

So the mistake was me not reading everything carefully. However there's a dichotomy to this approach where I would assume different behaviour. The `loaded()` method will return `true` or `false` **during the lifetime** of the Map object based on other factors - e.g. you might be adding different source data and layers asynchronously and this method would report `false`.

On the other hand, `load` event **will only fire once** during the lifetime of the Map object and I assume that happens when necessary default data/layers have been downloaded. So this naming is what confused me.

I've used the solution from [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10148) where I basically add `ready` method to the map object that will just tell me if the initial loading of the map has been done:

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({ ... })
map._isReady = false
map.ready = () => map._isReady
map.once('load', () => map._isReady = true))
```

This could be done more cleanly I guess by wrapping the `map` object in another class as to avoid monkey-patching but you get the point. After this I can adjust the code mentioned in question like this and it works as expected:

```
if (map.ready()) {
  map.addSource(id, source)
  map.addLayer(layer)
} else {
  map.on('load', () => {
    map.addSource(id, source)
    map.addLayer(layer)
  })
}
```

This solution will not however guard you against loading some layer dependent on some source sooner than you should. In that case you might want to look into [`data` events](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/events/#mapdataevent) and add custom logic.